# Invoking same call-template from others include files

Tags: xslt, include

I have a main.xsl. It invoke to A.xsl and B.xsl, both using the same call-template

```
<xsl:call-template name="setFormat">
  ...            
</xsl:call-template>
```

I want to use once the "setFormat" template instead of duplicate it in A.xsl and B.xsl, 
but when "setFormat" just is in one xsl the another one says "The named templete 'setFormat' does not exist"

I am using `xsl:include` to add the reference to main.xsl

What should I do?

I'm using MVS .Net 2005.

I'm working with main.xsl, main.xsl invoke to A.xsl and B.xsl:

> ```
> <xsl:include href="./A.xsl"/>
> <xsl:include href="./B.xsl"/>
> ```

Both A.xsl and B.xsl invoke to the same template using call-template, named  "setFormat"

"setFormat" cannot be in any part. Since if, por example, it is in A.xsl, B.xsl could not found it because is not in its scope or if it is in main.xsl A.xsl and B.xsl could not found it. Neither I'd want to duplicate it adding in A.xsl and B.xsl

How can I invoke to "setFormat" through call-template without duplicate it?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear from your question which of your three stylesheets is including which.

I think you mean that `A.xsl` and `B.xsl` each `xsl:include` `main.xsl` and that you either invoke `A.xsl` or `B.xsl` to process your document. In this case you should put the shared named template in `main.xsl` so it is seen in either case.

If on the other hand you mean that `main.xsl` uses `xsl:include` twice, to include both `A.xsl` and `B.xsl` and that you invoke `main.xsl` on your document, then there is only one code path and the named template can be in any of the three files.